# The Hopf invariant with coefficients other than Z.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

So generally one defines the Hopf invariant of a map $f: S^{2n-1} \to S^n$ as the coefficient $H(f)$ in  $\alpha^2 = H(f) \beta$ where $\langle \alpha \rangle = H^n(C_f)$ and $\langle \beta \rangle = H^{2n}(C_f)$.

I've looked around and asked a topologist or two, but I can't find any references to the same construction with coefficients. e.g. $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficients for instance. The nice bit about this would be that you can extend the statment that the Hopf invariant is 1 for all Hopf fibrations including the trivial one $S^0 \to S^1 \to \mathbb{RP}^1$. Where under normal considerations this would have Hopf invariant 0.

Does anyone know any reference to such a thing or is it possible that this offers no new information? It just seems like a natural extension of the concept, and in general having multiple coefficients you can work with often can differentiate things you couldn't before. I'm only blindly poking in the dark here but I found this interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot really obtain any new information.

Note that for cup product to be defined, you need the coefficient group $k$ to be a ring. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is initial in rings, there is exactly one map $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow k$ and this will induce a natural transformation $\phi: H^{*}(-, \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^{*}(-, k)$ of cohomology theories (the "change of coefficients").

Moreover, if you denote by $\alpha, \beta$ the canonical generators of $H^{n}(-, \mathbb{Z}), H^{2n}(-, \mathbb{Z})$, then $\alpha _{k} = \phi(\alpha), \beta _{k} = \phi(\beta)$ will be canonical generators of $H^{n}(-, k), H^{2n}(-, k)$. (To see this one might look at cellular complexes.) Therefore the equation $\alpha ^{2} = H(f) \beta$ will give you

$\alpha _{k} ^{2} = H (f) \beta _{k}$

and so the "Hopf invariant over $k$" will be an integer and in fact equal to $H(f)$.

Comment: This argument seems to break down for $n = 1$ if I understand it correctly. Note the following,  

$\alpha \in H^1(\mathbb{RP}^2, \mathbb{Z}_2)$ as a generator, then we have that 

$\alpha ^2 = \beta$ where $\beta \in H^2(\mathbb{RP}^2, \mathbb{Z}_2)$ is a generator.  

It looks like what you say works for any other $n > 1$ though. Would you still get that natural transformation using local coefficients though? They are a pretty different type of homology theory, but I'm not too familiar with them.

Comment: What do you mean by $n=1$ case..?

Comment: I'm using the $n$ from your post. When you have $S^{2n-1} \to S^n$ you define the hopf invariant as above. If $n$ is 1 your argument falls apart because the top cohomology group is not isolated from the middle cohomology group. i.e. it is false that $\phi(\beta)$ will be the canonical generator of $H^{2}(-,k)$ because the top cohomology group can pick up any torsion from $H^1(-,k)$ under the change of coordinates.
It seems that your argument works though when the top cohomology group is isolated from the middle one.